# Not able to call a function inside a class?

Tags: python, class

I am currently writing some code and have a main class (called "startup") and a secondary class which activates something on being called (called "Ringer"). All I want to do is initiate the Ringer class with `Ringer()`, and then do some code and when conditions are met, call `Ringer.__on()`. Same goes for `Ringer.__off()`.

Seems like I am doing something very simple wrong.

Below is some code of what I am trying to achieve... I am getting an `Attribute Error` with this.

```py
class Ringer:
    def __init__(self):
        print('__init__')
    def __on(self):
        print('turn on')
    def __off(self):
        print('turn off')

class start:
    def __init__(self):
        Ringer() #init something
        Ringer.__on() #call ONLY the on function
        Ringer.__off() #call ONLY the off function


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

The output of the above code should be

```
__init__
turn on
turn off
```

Comment: You are using double-underscores, thus name-mangling your attribute. why are you using two underscores? also, you've instantiated a `Ringer` object then immediately discard it, then try to call methods directly on the class. don't do that

Comment: This almost solved my issue... but now I have a problem of parameter self not being filled... any suggestions?

Comment: I already told you, you are trying to call your instance methods directly on the class. `Ringer.on()`, but `def on(self)` is designed to be an instance method, so `ringer = Ringer(); ringer.on()` You should probably read the [documentation on classes in python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: Ok thank you very much. This worked :)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but the answers to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1301346/1405065) contain good explanations of one of the main issues here.

Comment: You call `Ringer` to create an instance, not simply to trigger side effects in its `__init__` method.

Answer (score 0):

You use using double underscores in front of attribute names. The result is that the names are mangled. (eg. `__on` -> `_<insert class where __on is defined>__on`.)

So, you should be accessing `_Ringer__on` instead of `__on` Also, after you create an instance of `Ringer`, you don't do anything with it.

Instead I recommend binding the instance to an variable:

```py
ringer = Ringer()
ringer._Ringer__on()
ringer._Ringer__off()
```

So now that we know what the problem is, and how to fix it, a question arises:

> Why does python mangle attributes with double underscores?

Well, think of a light switch. And there is a cover on the light switch. Does this prevent you from using it? No! You can still use it, but you have to take off the cover first. The cover is ***protecting*** the light switch, not making it ***private***. And as you know, light switches can be dangerous. And the cover protects you! And that's why python name mangles. It's ***preventing accidental use***, not ***preventing you to access it***.

Now, where can this be helpful?

Well, if you have an attribute that you don't want accidental access to, you can name mangle. (eg. an `age` attribute.)

Example:

```py
class Animal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__age = 0
        print("My age is:", self.__age)


class Human(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        Animal.__init__(self)


john = Human()
print(john.__age)  # error!
print(john._Animal__age)  # ok
```